# Homebrew failed "Failed to download resource "sdformat""

Tags: gazebo-2.2, sdformat, homebrew

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello. I am using mac os x 10.9.4. I was using gazebo 2.2 with ogre1.7.4

Today I updated ogre to 1.9 therefore I re-install gazebo from homebrew. I did brew update but this error happened:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "sdformat"
Download failed: http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/sdformat-2.0.1.tar.bz2
```

As the homepage of gazebo was totally reformed, is there any patch to formula to fix this error?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6784/homebrew-failed-%22failed-to-download-resource-%22sdformat%22%22/) by [lockandfire](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/903/lockandfire/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the old links are working again. Sorry for the disruption. Also, feel free to post on the issue tracker for the homebrew tap:

https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/issues/25

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0